# PHP functions and variable scope in Smarty

Tags: php, global-variables, smarty, scope, smarty2

I'm working within [Smarty 2.6.27](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/). There is something that prevents PHP functions from accessing global variables:

```
{php}
  $a = "should be global";

  function test(){
    global $a;
    echo $a;
  }
  test();
{/php}
```

But the variable `$a` never makes it into the function. I've also done this:

```
{php}
  $a = "should be global";

  foreach ($GLOBALS as $key => $value) { 
     echo $key . "-" . $value;
  } 
{/php}
```

But again, `$a` does not make it into the list of PHP globals. It seems that this is because Smarty runs PHP in some odd context--for example, [the documentation mentions](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.php.tpl) this:

> To access PHP variables in {php} blocks you will need to use the PHP
>   global keyword.

I don't really need to get access to other PHP globals, and I don't particularly want the scope of variables created here to go wider, I simply need to figure out how to use variables defined outside of the functions *in* the function. There will be a *lot* of these variables, so passing them as parameters is impractical.

Comment: This is how you `{assign}` a global variable in Smarty: `{assign var=foo value="bar" scope="global"}`

Comment: I'm working within PHP within Smarty, so this seems a little cumbersome. I would have to turn PHP off, assign the Smarty variable, then turn PHP back on--would the Smart variable even be available to PHP as a variable after that?

Comment: I just tried `{assign var=a value="works?" scope="global"}{php}echo "{/php}{$a}{php}";{/php}` but it does not `echo` out anything. I don't think Smarty and PHP are meant to play together this way.

Comment: The "outside the box" answer here is that you should not be using `{php}` blocks in Smarty in the first place. The whole point of Smarty is that the template logic can be written in Smarty; mixing in raw PHP defeats the whole object.

Comment: @IMSoP I hear you. I don't know WHMCS templates require Smarty, and yet the internal API for WHMCS doesn't work without straight up PHP.

Comment: @brentonstrine Then it might be good to ask more specifically what you are trying to achieve in WHMCS; perhaps there is a less hacky solution?

Comment: @IMSoP You're right, but I am not really sure how to phrase the question--the official documentation for WHMCS encourages `{php}` all throughout. I think it's just poorly designed software.

Comment: @brentonstrine Heh. Maybe the solution is to avoid that software then! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, for the record **I strongly recommend avoiding both `{php}` blocks in Smarty, and global variables**. Try to find some other solution to the underlying problem.

That out of the way, you quote this line from the manual, but you haven't followed its advice:

> To access PHP variables in {php} blocks you will need to use the PHP global keyword.

What it means is this:

```
{php}
  global $a;
  $a = "should be global";
{/php}
```

Without that, the variable `$a` is scoped to whatever function context the generated code is run in. There is no special consideration for "nested" functions or scopes in PHP, so a variable is either global, or visible only inside that one function.

Comment: Ah, I'd tried that but I guess I had another problem that made it seem like it wasn't working. This fixed it, though I really do with it didn't have to be GLOBAL global. Oh well!